# Let $S$ be a subset of $G$ such that for any $x,y \in G$ , $xS ; yS$ are either disjoint or equal , then is $S$ a left coset of some subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group , for any subset $S$ of $G$ and $g \in G$ , let $gS:=\{gs:s\in S\}$ ; Now suppose $S$ is a subset of $G$ such that for any $x,y \in G$ , either $xS \cap y S = \varnothing$ or else $xS=yS$ , then is it true that $S=gH$ for some subgroup $H$ of $G$ and some $g \in G$ ?

Comment: So some set $gS$ contains the identity. Show that $gS$ is a subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S \ne \emptyset$, this is true.

Let $g \in S$, and let $H = g^{-1}S$. Then $S = gH$ (clearly), and $H \le G$ (to be proved).

*Proof:* First, observe that for all $t \in S$, we have the identity element $1 \in t^{-1}S$, which implies that $t^{-1}S = g^{-1}S = H$ (by the given property of $S$). Therefore, $\forall t \in S, tH = S$.

Since $S$ is non-empty, so is $H$. Let $x, y \in H$. In order to show that $H \le G$, it is enough to show that $x^{-1}y \in H$. Since $H = g^{-1}S$, there are elements $r, s \in S$ such that $x = g^{-1}r$, $y = g^{-1}s$. Then $x^{-1}y = r^{-1}s$.

But $r \in S \implies rH = S$, so that $\exists h \in H, rh = s$ (since $s \in S$). Then, $r^{-1}s = h \in H$. This proves that for all $x, y \in H$, $x^{-1}y \in H$, and therefore, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. $\quad \square$